# Remote stream recording in Firefox fails

Tags: firefox, webrtc, recording

I'm using `MediaStreamRecorder.js` to record remote audio and video stream.

In Firefox (version 39), I could not initiate recording, it throws:

> Security Error : operation is insecure.

How do I do remote stream recording (both audio and video) in Firefox?

Comment: This is a crossorigin problem. Do you load the javascript from another website?

Comment: I kept a local copy of javascript and used that for my code.

Comment: Show us some code or we won't be able to help you.